# Easiest way to grab status.text from a status.id in python-twitter?

Tags: python, django, twitter

I'm using a Twitter client that replies to tweets made with python-twitter and django. When you reply to a tweet, in your status' properties, you have access to in_reply_to_screen_name/status_id/user_name/user_id.

My question is, what's the easiest way to grab the seemingly non-existant 'in_reply_to_text' (what i need) property?

Comment: This doesn't answer your question, but maybe use Tweepy instead? It's in much more active development and most people prefer this to python-twitter. https://github.com/tweepy/tweepy